# Adding specific passenget to a file

Tags: java

I have to add to each plane file  a specific passanger as they are added to the plane

Ex: `plane1  = p1 = new Passanger("Victor", "Mihai", 28);`

So inside file `Beoing.txt` I will have only `Passanger{name='Victor', surname='Mihai', age=28}`

But instead  I have all of them in each file and that is not what I want to have.

The following code I made is adding all the passangers , but I cannot find the way to add only the one who is added to the plane.

My Passenger class:

```java
public class Passanger {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;

    public Passanger(String name, String surname, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Passanger{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My Plane class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Plane {
   
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private int spaces;
    List<Passanger> passangers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Plane(String name, String color, int spaces) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.spaces = spaces;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getSpaces() {
        return spaces;
    }

    public void setSpaces(int spaces) {
        this.spaces = spaces;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Plane{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", spaces=" + spaces +
                '}';
    }

    public void addPassanger(Passanger newPassanger) {
        passangers.add(newPassanger);
    }
}
```

My main:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Passanger p1 = new Passanger("Victor", "Mihai", 28);
        Passanger p2 = new Passanger("Alex", "Olan", 25);
        Passanger p3 = new Passanger("Vlad", "Pioter", 23);

        List<Passanger> passengerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3));

        Plane plane1 = new Plane("Beoing", "red", 200);
        plane1.addPassanger(p1);
        Plane plane2 = new Plane("Mig", "gray", 2);
        plane2.addPassanger(p2);
        Plane plane3 = new Plane("jet", "blue", 10);
        plane3.addPassanger(p3);
        List<Plane> planeList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(plane1, plane2, plane3));
        writePassengersOnPlaneFile(passengerList, planeList);
    }

    public static void writePassengersOnPlaneFile(List<Passanger> passengerList, List<Plane> planeList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < passengerList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < planeList.size(); j++) {
                try {
                    //This write all the passangers to each file
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(planeList.get(j).getName() + ".txt", true);

                    //here I must take passanger per plane added but I do not get it how,(any hint please?)
                    fileWriter.write(passengerList.get(i).toString() + "\n");

                    fileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please give me a hint ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to create a getter for `List<Passanger> passangers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate through the planes first, then make a getter for the passenger list inside the plane and iterate through those.

```java
public class Plane {
  // ...
  public List<Passanger> getPassengers() {
    return this.passangers;
  }
}
```

You also need to make sure you create one file writer per plane:

```java
 public static void writePassengersOnPlaneFile(List<Plane> planeList) {
    for (int j = 0; j < planeList.size(); j++) {
        Plane plane = planeList.get(j);
        try { 
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(plane.getName() + ".txt", true);
            for (int i = 0; i < plane.getPassengers().size(); i++) {
                Passanger passenger = plane.getPassengers().get(i);
                fileWriter.write(passenger.toString() + "\n");
            }
            fileWriter.close();
         } catch (IOException exception) {
             exception.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is ture indeed, i did not  head    `public List<Passanger> getPassengers() {
    return this.passangers;
  }` 
As  Scary Wombat said above. 
And regarding fille per plane, the filles are already created , I just needed to write inside each file  the passengers
Thanks for help  * Multumec Frumos :)*